# Dynamically populated drop-down; $_POST returning error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pw") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());



$sql = "SELECT machine_id FROM machines";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<form action='results_send.php' method='post' >";
echo "<select name='machine_id'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['machine_id'] . "'>" . $row['machine_id'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select></form>";
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';



$machine = $_POST['machine_id'];

var_dump($machine);

?>
```

returns:

```
<form action='results_send.php' method='post' ><select name='machine_id'><option value='2011 Honda'>2011 Honda</option><option value='1999 Toyota'>1999 Toyota</option><option value='1999 Honda'>1999 Honda</option><option value='1999 Honda'>1999 Honda</option><option value='2013 Toyota'>2013 Toyota</option><option value='2012 Ford'>2012 Ford</option><option value='2012 Ford'>2012 Ford</option><option value='2012 Ford'>2012 Ford</option><option value='2012 Ford'>2012 Ford</option></select></form><input type="submit" value="Submit">NULL
```

all of this is on the same document: results_send.php

I've been trying out php/mysql for only a couple days--the patience is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you're banging together queries by hand rather than using a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/)? Also you should **not** be using `mysql_query` in new code. It is scheduled to be removed from future versions of PHP and is dangerously insecure if not used perfectly.

Comment: Can you provide us with a var_dump() or print_r() of your $_POST? I believe that you're not passing data as you're expecting, causing the undefined index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you want $_POST to return any value or even want us to understand your problem while you don't explain how you're submitting your form.

you have to use one of 2 solutions for your case:

- To use AJAX
- To use two different forms with a submit buttons that have different names. Then use isset($_POST['name_of_button']) to check which form is submitted upon posting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, you're missing the opening quote on the `value` attribute:

Change to:

```
echo "<option value=\"";
```

Or

```
echo '<option value="';
```

You're also missing a closing `</form>` tag. If you are ajaxing this script and inserting the content into a page where there's other forms then the missing form tag can be a problem.

It's also worth passing any data through `htmlspecialchars()` when you output it into HTML, to prevent XSS and syntax errors where the data may include quotes.

Comment: While you are correct, this doesn't even remotely answer the question.

Comment: @PeteSorensen if `$_POST['machine']` is still not present after the syntax fix, view the generated HTML source and update the question so I can see what the browser is getting. Also see my edit about the closing `</form>` tag.