# PHP: Populating a drop-down from database; sending result to new query

Tags: php, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I already have posted an unanswered question ([Dynamically populated drop-down; $_POST returning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818816/dynamically-populated-drop-down-post-returning-error) ) that deals with the specifics of my case, but it hasn't gained much traction, so I thought I'd go another route.

Would anyone be willing to instruct me on how to perform this simple task:

I have two tables.

I want to populate a drop down menu from the results of a query from one table:

I want to take the $_POST from this drop-down and perform a query on the second table and print those results.

Sounds simple right? I've been pulling my hair out trying find help to make it work. See the link in the first paragraph to see the specifics of my problem, or if that's the wrong route, please instruct me in broad terms how to accomplish this.

Comment: See my comment on your other post. I don't think it's necessary to start another post (you're pretty close anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to get is usually called "Chained selects", you are missing one immportant step, Javascript (or just use jQuery) to make AJAX calls to populate the second select.

Try with a simple tutorial: Chained Select Boxes using PHP / MySQL / AJAX / jQuery http://www.blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes-using-php-mysql-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange=""` to trigger a AJAX request to query based on the value.
or with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".machine_select").change(function(){
        //do ajax and replace response with html() or such
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```